# Are two triangles similar?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, geometry, 2d

As a part time project I am working on some geometry utilities and have come across a relatively simple question that seems to have a not so simple solution.

The problem involves EPSILON being too small for the problem. To see if two triangle are similar I workout the 3 interior angles in the form of their cosines for each triangle and then sort them. I then test `Math.abs(t1[0]-t2[0]) < EPSILON` where t1 is the one triangle and t2 the other each containing the three angles.

I am getting about a 20% - 80% failure rate on triangles I know to be similar. When I bring EPSILON to a larger value, for example still a very small 0.0000001 there is no failure ( well not in the time I have let the tests run).

Below is the extracted relevant triangle function and I have also included the testing code as a demo below that. Click the button and its runs tests and shows the results. The triangles are randomly generated. Every so often two similar triangle are created of which about half are exact copies and the rest are a copy but scaled, mirrored, rotated and vec order shuffled while still maintaining the similarity

I would like to know how to calculate a reasonable EPSILON that will reduce the incorrect results but keep the system as accurate as possible?

Though there is also the possibility that there is another error in the test code which I will continue to check.

```
    const EPSILON =  Number.EPSILON
    function Triangle(p1,p2,p3){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
    }
    Triangle.prototype.p1 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.p2 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.p3 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.isSimilar = function(triangle){
        var a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,aa1,bb1,cc1,aa2,bb2,cc2; // 
        var t1 = [];
        var t2 = [];
        var sortF = function(a,b){ return a-b };
        // get the length squared and length of each side
        a1 = Math.sqrt(aa1 = Math.pow(this.p1.x - this.p2.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p1.y - this.p2.y, 2));
        b1 = Math.sqrt(bb1 = Math.pow(this.p2.x - this.p3.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p2.y - this.p3.y, 2));
        c1 = Math.sqrt(cc1 = Math.pow(this.p3.x - this.p1.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p3.y - this.p1.y, 2));
        a2 = Math.sqrt(aa2 = Math.pow(triangle.p1.x - triangle.p2.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p1.y - triangle.p2.y, 2));
        b2 = Math.sqrt(bb2 = Math.pow(triangle.p2.x - triangle.p3.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p2.y - triangle.p3.y, 2));
        c2 = Math.sqrt(cc2 = Math.pow(triangle.p3.x - triangle.p1.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p3.y - triangle.p1.y, 2));

        // get the cosin of each angle for both triangle
        t1[0] = (cc1 - (aa1 + bb1)) / (-2 * a1 * b1);        
        t1[1] = (aa1 - (cc1 + bb1)) / (-2 * c1 * b1);        
        t1[2] = (bb1 - (cc1 + aa1)) / (-2 * c1 * a1);        
        t2[0] = (cc2 - (aa2 + bb2)) / (-2 * a2 * b2);        
        t2[1] = (aa2 - (cc2 + bb2)) / (-2 * c2 * b2);        
        t2[2] = (bb2 - (cc2 + aa2)) / (-2 * c2 * a2);         
        t1.sort(sortF);
        t2.sort(sortF);

        if(Math.abs(t1[0] - t2[0]) < EPSILON && Math.abs(t1[1] - t2[1]) < EPSILON && Math.abs(t1[2] - t2[2]) < EPSILON){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    function Vec(x,y){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
    }
    Vec.prototype.x = undefined;
    Vec.prototype.y = undefined;
```

**UPDATE**

Some more information.

Failed similar triangle using cosine of angles EPSILON : 2.220446049250313e-16

```
Failed Triangles ID : 94
Method : compare cosine of angles 
Both Compare T1 to T2 and T2 to T1 failed
Both Triangles known to be similare

Triangle 1
p1.x = -149241116087155.97;
p1.y = -1510074922190599.8;
p2.x = -2065214078816255.8;
p2.y = 6756872141691895;
p3.x = -7125027429739231;
p3.y = -5622578541875555;

Triangle 2
p1.x = -307440480802857.2;
p1.y = -404929352172871.56;
p2.x = -3020163594243123;
p2.y = -355583557775981.75;
p3.x = 595422457974710.8;
p3.y = 2291176238828451.5;

Compare T1 to T2 Result : false
Computed values 
Triangle 1 length of side and square length
length a : 8486068945686473 squared : 7.201336615094433e+31
length b : 13373575078230092 squared : 1.78852510373057e+32
length c : 8097794805726894 squared : 6.557428071565746e+31
Unsorted cosines C is angle opposite side c
cosine C : 0.8163410767815653
cosine A : 0.7960251614312384
cosine B : -0.30024590551189423
ratio a : undefined
ratio b : undefined
ratio c : undefined

Triangle2
length a : 2713171888697380.5 squared : 7.36130169761771e+30
length b : 4480825808030667.5 squared : 2.0077799921913682e+31
length c : 2843263414467020.5 squared : 8.08414684404666e+30
Unsorted cosines C is angle opposite side c
cosine C : 0.7960251614312384
cosine A : 0.8163410767815651
cosine B : -0.3002459055118942

Compare T2 to T1 Result : false
Triangle1
Computed values 
Triangle 1 length of side and square length
length a : 2713171888697380.5 squared : 7.36130169761771e+30
length b : 4480825808030667.5 squared : 2.0077799921913682e+31
length c : 2843263414467020.5 squared : 8.08414684404666e+30
Unsorted cosines C is angle opposite side c
cosine a : 0.7960251614312384
cosine b : 0.8163410767815651
cosine c : -0.3002459055118942
ratio a : undefined
ratio b : undefined
ratio c : undefined

Triangle2
length a : 8486068945686473 squared : 7.201336615094433e+31
length b : 13373575078230092 squared : 1.78852510373057e+32
length c : 8097794805726894 squared : 6.557428071565746e+31
cosine a : 0.8163410767815653
cosine b : 0.7960251614312384
cosine c : -0.30024590551189423
```

**UPDATE 2**

Results output and a bug fix (apologies @lhf I did not sqrt epsilon I was still using the original constant)

This shows the results of tests on the same set of triangles. Inconsistency means that comparing triangle 1 to triangle 2 is a different result than triangle 2 to 1. Incorrect Means that two known similar triangles failed and Incorrect Inconsistency means that two known similar triangle failed one test and passed the other.

Using the ratios of lengths gave the worst result but using cosine was not much better apart from the  Incorrect Inconsistency similar triangles which had a very high rate of inconsistency between compare t1 to t2 and t2 to t1 using the ratio of length. But that makes sense are the magnitude of the ratios will vary greatly depending on which order the test is done.

As you can see using the square root of EPSILON completely eliminated the error for both methods.

If **lhf** wishes to put the sqrt(epsilon) comment as an answer I will accept that as an answer. And thanks to everyone for their input and I have some further reading thanks to Salix

```
======================================
Default EPSILON : 2.220446049250313e-16
======================================
Via cosine of angles
All Inconsistency failed : 0 of 10000
Similar Incorrect failed : 1924 of 5032
Similar Incorrect Inconsistency failed : 0 of 5032
======================================
Via ratio of lengths
All Inconsistency failed : 1532 of 10000
Similar Incorrect failed : 2082 of 5032
Similar Incorrect Inconsistency failed : 1532 of 5032
======================================
Squaring EPSILON : 1.4901161193847656e-8
======================================
Via cosine of angles
All Inconsistency failed : 0 of 10000
Similar Incorrect failed : 0 of 5032
Similar Incorrect Inconsistency failed : 0 of 5032
======================================
Via ratio of lengths
All Inconsistency failed : 0 of 10000
Similar Incorrect failed : 0 of 5032
Similar Incorrect Inconsistency failed : 0 of 5032
```

```js
const EPSILON =  Number.EPSILON
    function Triangle(p1,p2,p3){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
    }
    Triangle.prototype.p1 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.p2 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.p3 = undefined;
    Triangle.prototype.isSimilar = function(triangle){
        var a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,aa1,bb1,cc1,aa2,bb2,cc2; // 
        var t1 = [];
        var t2 = [];
        var sortF = function(a,b){ return a-b };
        // get the length squared and length of each side
        a1 = Math.sqrt(aa1 = Math.pow(this.p1.x - this.p2.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p1.y - this.p2.y, 2));
        b1 = Math.sqrt(bb1 = Math.pow(this.p2.x - this.p3.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p2.y - this.p3.y, 2));
        c1 = Math.sqrt(cc1 = Math.pow(this.p3.x - this.p1.x, 2) +  Math.pow(this.p3.y - this.p1.y, 2));
        a2 = Math.sqrt(aa2 = Math.pow(triangle.p1.x - triangle.p2.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p1.y - triangle.p2.y, 2));
        b2 = Math.sqrt(bb2 = Math.pow(triangle.p2.x - triangle.p3.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p2.y - triangle.p3.y, 2));
        c2 = Math.sqrt(cc2 = Math.pow(triangle.p3.x - triangle.p1.x, 2) +  Math.pow(triangle.p3.y - triangle.p1.y, 2));

        // get the cosin of each angle for both triangle
        t1[0] = (cc1 - (aa1 + bb1)) / (-2 * a1 * b1);        
        t1[1] = (aa1 - (cc1 + bb1)) / (-2 * c1 * b1);        
        t1[2] = (bb1 - (cc1 + aa1)) / (-2 * c1 * a1);        
        t2[0] = (cc2 - (aa2 + bb2)) / (-2 * a2 * b2);        
        t2[1] = (aa2 - (cc2 + bb2)) / (-2 * c2 * b2);        
        t2[2] = (bb2 - (cc2 + aa2)) / (-2 * c2 * a2);         
        t1.sort(sortF);
        t2.sort(sortF);

        if(Math.abs(t1[0] - t2[0]) < EPSILON && Math.abs(t1[1] - t2[1]) < EPSILON && Math.abs(t1[2] - t2[2]) < EPSILON){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    function Vec(x,y){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
    }
    Vec.prototype.x = undefined;
    Vec.prototype.y = undefined;

    var iterations = 1000;  // number of tests
    var presentSimilar = 1/2; // odds of similar triangle
    var presentSuperSimilar = 1/2; // odds of triangles being identical 
    var presentInfinity = 0;//1/20; // odds of a divide by zero
    var presentDegenerate = 0;//1/100; // odds of a degenerate triangle can be colinear or degenerate right triangle     
    var v; // temp for swap
    var xdx,xdy,ydx,ydy;  // vars for rotation
    var copyVec = [["p1","p2","p3"],["p2","p3","p1"],["p3","p1","p2"]];     // pick a vec for selecting vecs
    
    // the triangles for testing;
    var tri1 = new Triangle(new Vec(0,0), new Vec(0,0), new Vec(0,0));
    var tri2 = new Triangle(new Vec(0,0), new Vec(0,0), new Vec(0,0));
    // max Random
    function rMax(){
        return ((Math.random()*2)-1) * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    }
    // rotate function
    function rotate(vec){
       var x = vec.x;
       var y = vec.y;
       vec.x = x * xdx + y * ydx;
       vec.y = x * xdy + y * ydy;
    };
    function translateVec(vec,x,y){
        vec.x += x;
        vec.y += y;
    }
    function translateTriangle(tri,x,y){
        translateVec(tri.p1);
        translateVec(tri.p2);
        translateVec(tri.p3);
    }
        

    // make infinite vec to simulate the result of a divide by zero
    function doInfinity(vec){
        if(Math.random() < presentInfinity){
            if(Math.random() < 0.5){
                vec.x = Infinity;
                vec.y = Infinity;
            }else{
                vec.x = -Infinity;
                vec.y = -Infinity;
            }
        }
    }
    // create a random vector;
    function randomVec(vec){
        vec.x = rMax();
        vec.y = rMax();
        doInfinity(vec);
    }
    // create a random triangle
    function randomTriangle(tri){
        var p,r;
        randomVec(tri.p1);
        randomVec(tri.p2);
        randomVec(tri.p3);
        if(Math.random() < presentDegenerate){
            r = Math.random();
            if(r < 1/3){ // Degenerate right triangle
                p = copyVec[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]; // get two vec to be at the same location
                tri[p[0]].x = tri[p[1]].x;
                tri[p[0]].y = tri[p[1]].y;
            }else // Degenerate colinear triangle
            if(r < 2/3){
                p = copyVec[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]; // get two vec to be at the same location
                r = Math.random();
                tri[p[0]].x = (tri[p[1]].x - tri[p[2]].x) * r + tri[p[2]].x;
                tri[p[0]].y = (tri[p[1]].y - tri[p[2]].y) * r + tri[p[2]].y;
            }else{ // degenerate undimentioned triangle. Has not area
                tri.p1.x = tri.p2.x = tri.p3.x;
                tri.p1.y = tri.p2.y = tri.p3.y;
            }    
        }
    }
    function runTest(){
        var result1,result2,mustBeSimilar;
        var countSimilar = 0;
        var countNorm = 0;
        var error1 = 0;
        var error2 = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i ++){
            randomTriangle(tri1);
            if(Math.random() < presentSimilar){
                mustBeSimilar = true;
                countSimilar += 1;
                tri2.p1.x = tri1.p1.x;
                tri2.p1.y = tri1.p1.y;
                tri2.p2.x = tri1.p2.x;
                tri2.p2.y = tri1.p2.y;
                tri2.p3.x = tri1.p3.x;
                tri2.p3.y = tri1.p3.y;
                if(Math.random() >= presentSuperSimilar){
                    if(Math.random() < 0.5){  // swap two
                        v = tri2.p1;
                        tri2.p1 = tri2.p2;
                        tri2.p2 = v;     
                    }
                    if(Math.random() < 0.5){  // swap two
                        v = tri2.p2;
                        tri2.p2 = tri2.p3;
                        tri2.p3 = v;     
                    }
                    if(Math.random() < 0.5){  // swap two
                        v = tri2.p1;
                        tri2.p1 = tri2.p3;
                        tri2.p3 = v;     
                    }
                    // scale and or mirror the second triangle
                    v = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    tri2.p1.x *= v;
                    tri2.p1.y *= v;
                    tri2.p2.x *= v;
                    tri2.p2.y *= v;
                    tri2.p3.x *= v;
                    tri2.p3.y *= v;
                    // rotate the triangle
                    v = (Math.random()- 0.5) * Math.PI * 4;
                    ydy = xdx = Math.cos(v);
                    ydx = -(xdy = Math.sin(v));
                    rotate(tri2.p1);
                    rotate(tri2.p2);
                    rotate(tri2.p3);
                }
            }else{
                randomTriangle(tri2);
                mustBeSimilar = false;
            }
            countNorm += 1;
            result1 = tri1.isSimilar(tri2);
            result2 = tri2.isSimilar(tri1);  
            if(result1 !== result2){
                error1 += 1;
            }
            if(mustBeSimilar && (!result1 || !result2)){
                error2 += 1;
            }
            for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                translateTriangle(tri1,Math.random(),Math.random());
                translateTriangle(tri2,Math.random(),Math.random());
                if(mustBeSimilar){
                    countSimilar += 1;
                }
                countNorm += 1;
                result1a = tri1.isSimilar(tri2);
                result2a = tri2.isSimilar(tri1);   
                if(result1a !== result2a || result1 !== result1a || result2 !== result2a){
                    error1 += 1;
                }
                if(mustBeSimilar && (!result1a || !result2a)){
                    error2 += 1;
                }
            }      
        }
        divResult1.textContent = "Inconsistancy result failed : "+error1 + " of "+ countNorm;
        divResult2.textContent = "Incorrect result failed : "+error2 + " of "+ countSimilar
    }
    var button = document.createElement("input"); 
    button.type = "button"
    button.value = "Run test"
    button.onclick = runTest;
    var divResult1 = document.createElement("div"); 
    var divResult2 = document.createElement("div"); 
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.body.appendChild(divResult1);
    document.body.appendChild(divResult2);
```

Comment: Can you specify what it means for triangles to be "close"? Is scaling ok? Rotation?

Comment: @starmole Similar triangle are similar when the angles at each corner are the same, they can be mirrored, rotated, scaled, and translated and that will not affect them being similar.

Comment: @maioman reasonable EPSILON would be the smallest number that gives to most true answers for known similar triangles while not increasing false negatives for dissimilar triangles.

Comment: Try `EPSILON = Math.sqrt(Number.EPSILON)`.

Comment: by "scaled" do you include -ve factors? if so just compare the ratios of the lengths of the sides.

Comment: @willywonka Using ratios reduces the accuracy of the test, the reason I have explained in the comment to Salis_alba's answer

Comment: @lhf Yes EPSILON squared may be on the right track. The square itself has made no difference but this is because the test is a statistical comparison less than 0.1% is lost in the noise, I will rewrite the test to allow more conclusive comparison as it looks like I will have to find EPSILON by seeing if the result approaches some sort of limit.

Comment: @lhf My bad I meant square root not square in last comment..

Comment: Have you got examples of triangles for which your tests fail?

Comment: @Salixalba will get back to you when I have completed the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Following willywokka's comment. You may be able to just see if there is a single scale factor.

```
// get the length squared and length of each side
a1 = Math.sqrt(...);
....

// Sort the values so a1 < b1 < c1, a2 < b2 < c2
if(b1 < a1) { tmp = b1; b1 = a1; a1 = tmp }
if(c1 < a1) { tmp = c1; c1 = a1; a1 = tmp }
if(c1 < b1) { tmp = c1; c1 = b1; b1 = tmp }
if(b2 < a2) { tmp = b2; b2 = a2; a2 = tmp }
if(c2 < a2) { tmp = c2; c2 = a2; a2 = tmp }
if(c2 < b2) { tmp = c2; c2 = b2; b2 = tmp }

// work out the scale factors
ka = a2 / a1;
kb = b2 / b1;
kc = c2 / c1;

if( abs(ka - kb) < epsilon && abs(kc - ka) < epsilon && abs(kc - kb) < epsilon )
   // similar
else
   // not similar
```

Rather than working with an absolute epsilon you might want one which is within x% of the value. So that the values are considered equal if ka - x% < kb < ka + x%, that is (1-x/100) ka < kb < (1+x/100) ka. Or (1-x/100) < kb/ka < (1+x/100), or abs(kb/ka) < x/100.

---

There is a statistically more rigorous approach to the problem. This would involve a pretty precise definition of what we mean by similar and examining the distribution of triangles. [Statistical shape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_shape_analysis) is a poor starting point. [David George Kendall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_George_Kendall) did work examining the shape of triangles.

Comment: Thank you for the time but using the scale ratio to compare the triangle actually decreases the accuracy of the test by about 2%  and how I did it originally. This is because the ratio is unbound and can be any value > 0 and the larger the number the less reliable epsilon becomes. While the cosine of the angles is bound to -1 <= c <= 1 which is something I though would allow for a better estimate of a reasonable EPSILON. I'll give a +1 as it is a more efficient solution, but not an answer to the problem.

Comment: @Blindman67 really? that bad? try _square_ ratios instead to avoid the `sqrt` bit. i know js uses single precision but still...

Comment: It might be work to consider ratios which are percentage differences rather than a fixed absolute amount. See my updated answer for one strategy.

Comment: @willywonka will try square ratios but currently rewriting the test. Will come back with results ASAP

Comment: @Salixalba Thanks will investigate your updated answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really just angles, you can simply compute the three inner angles of both triangles. Just use the cosine,

```
cos(angle) = dot (normalized(edge[i]),normalized(edge[(i+1)%3])). 
with edge[i] = p[(i+1)%3] - p[i].
```

So you have three cos(angle) for each triangle one and two. Then just check every permutation. A triangle has only six permutations. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)

```
besterr = max;
for i=1..6 perm(i) in tri1
  for j=1..6 perm(j) in tri2
    err = 0
    for k=1..3 angle
      err += abs(angletri1[perm[i,k]] - angletri2[perm[j,k]])
    if (err<besterr) besterr = err; 
return besterr;
```

Does that give your expected result? We certainly can do more efficient. But this is the brute force test algorithm. One thing to note is that it only works for triangles - any vertex permutation in a triangle is the same triangle outline. That would not be the case for a bigger polygon.

Once this works you can start experimenting. Do you get the same result for angle and cos(angle)? For err += abs(d) and err += d*d? Can you just check 2 permutations by sorting angles? Remember triangle angles sum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_angles_of_a_triangle). What computations are redundant?

And finally: Is it really the metric you want? Are two triangles with opposite winding really similar? A huge and a tiny one?

Comment: Rather than using the dot product, i used cosine law cos(ang) = (c<sup>2</sup>-a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>)/(2ab) where a,b,c are lengths ang is angle opposite c. This avoids the normalise and additional error ( but I will check that).  Math.acos has different implementations and results across browsers thus I avoided using it. There may be a way to optimise the sort by finding an early exit not completing the sort and able to return not similar. It got messy with the fact that triangle can be left or right handed, I just could not find a way to know without sorting, Catch 22

Comment: Just try all the permutations. A triangle has only 6 permutations. And all of them are the same outline. Do that first, then, later, worry about optimizing.